# Iterating through a list of series for plotting

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a list of series where each series is 100 observations of the time it took to parse some data.

```
list_series = [Series1, Series2, Series3...]
```

When I try to plot the series individually, I would do something like

```
# generate subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# histplot
sns.histplot(data=Series1, ax=ax, color='deepskyblue', kde=True, alpha=0.3)
# title
ax.set_title(f'Parsing times for Series1: Mean = {np.mean(Series1):0.4}, Median = {np.median(Series1):0.4}')
# fix overlap
fig.tight_layout()
```

simple enough, and the plot looks good.

[image]

However, when I put this process through a loop, using list_series, the plots end up becoming wonky using pretty much the same method except through a loop:

```
list_series = [Series1, Series2, Series3...]

for i in list_series:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.histplot(data=i, ax=ax, color='deepskyblue', kde=True, alpha=0.3)
    ax.set_title(f'Parsing times for {i}: Mean = {np.mean(i):0.4}, Median = {np.median(i):0.4}')
    fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: don't worry about mean/median not matching first plot, I did some order shuffling]

The name of the Series in the title gets replaced with the index number, and the head and tail of the series gets squished above the actual plot...

(don't worry about mean/median not matching up, I did some order shuffling within the list during trials)

Is there something I'm not understanding as to how loops or plotting works?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to use `i.name` for the series name?

Comment: I wanted the Series names just be exactly what the Series are. Series1,2,3... so on.
What is the use case for i.name in your comment? I am not familiar with that.

Comment: If `i` is a `Series`, then you want its [`.name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html), right?

Comment: I understand now! I was calling the entire object into the fstring literal in the title. not the name. thank you